# What is wrong with the parameters of this method/Why am I getting this error?

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, parameters, playing-cards

I have included three classes that I have written in this question. One is a Card class, representing a playing card:

```
public class Card 
{
    int theRank, theSuit, theCard;

    public Card(int suit, int rank)
    { 
     theRank = rank;
     theSuit = suit;
    }

    public String getRank()
    {
     String rankString = "";

     switch (theRank)
     {
         case 1:
             rankString = "Ace";
         case 2: 
             rankString = "2";
         case 3:
             rankString = "3";
         case 4:
             rankString = "4";
         case 5:
             rankString = "5";
         case 6:
             rankString = "6";
         case 7:
             rankString = "7";
         case 8:
             rankString = "8";
         case 9:
             rankString = "9";
         case 10:
             rankString = "10";
         case 11:
             rankString = "Jack";
         case 12:
             rankString = "Queen";
         case 13:
             rankString = "King";
      }

      return rankString;
    }

    public String getSuit()
    {
     String suitString = "";

     switch(theSuit)
     {
         case 1:
             suitString = "Diamonds";
         case 2:
             suitString = "Hearts";
         case 3:
             suitString = "Clubs";
         case 4:
             suitString = "Spades";
     }

     return suitString;
  }
}
```

The other is a class Deck, that represents an arrayList of Card objects:

```
public class Deck 
{

    public ArrayList<Card> loadDeck(ArrayList<Card> deck)
    {
     for (int suit = 1; suit <= 4; suit++)
     {
      for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++)
      {
       deck.add(new Card(suit, rank));
      }
     }

    return deck;
 }

 public void shuffleDeck(ArrayList<Card> deck)
 {
    Card temp;
    int index;
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = deck.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
     index = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
     temp = deck.get(index);
     deck.add(index, deck.get(i));
     temp = deck.get(i);
    }

 }

public ArrayList dealHand(ArrayList<Card> deck)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>(8);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
     int suit = rand.nextInt(3);
     int rank = rand.nextInt(51);
     Card temp = new Card(suit, rank);
     hand.add(i, temp);
     deck.remove(temp);


    }

    return hand;
}

public void printHand(ArrayList<Card> hand)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
     Card temp = hand.get(0);
     System.out.println(temp.getRank() + " of " + temp.getSuit());

    }
}

}
```

I then have a class GoFish that contains the main method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GoFish 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
        deck.loadDeck(deck);
    }
}
```

In the main method I create an arrayList of Card objects called "deck". The loadDeck() method is supposed to take an empty arrayList (intended for Card objects) as a parameter, and loads it with Card objects that replicate a standard deck of 52 playing cards. I'm getting an error in the main method class that I don't understand, though I think it has something to do with the parameters of the loadDeck() method. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `loadDeck()` is a method on `Deck`, you don't have a `Deck`, you have an `ArrayList<Card>`.

Comment: the error message says "cannot find symbol, symbol: methodLoadDeck(ArrayList<Card>), location: variable deck of type ArrayList<Card>"

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList does not have a method `loadDeck()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    deck.loadDeck(deck);
}
```

You want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Deck testDeck = new Deck();
    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    deck = testDeck.loadDeck(deck);
}
```

***************UPDATE You might want something like this?************************

```
public class Deck 
{
    private ArrayList<Card> deck;

    public Deck()
    {
        deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
        loadDeck();
    }

    public void loadDeck()
    {
     for (int suit = 1; suit <= 4; suit++)
     {
      for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++)
      {
       deck.add(new Card(suit, rank));
      }
     }

    return deck;
 }

 public void shuffleDeck(ArrayList<Card> deck)
 {
    Card temp;
    int index;
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = deck.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
     index = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
     temp = deck.get(index);
     deck.add(index, deck.get(i));
     temp = deck.get(i);
    }

 }

public ArrayList<Card> dealHand()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>(8);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
     int suit = rand.nextInt(3);
     int rank = rand.nextInt(51);
     Card temp = new Card(suit, rank);
     hand.add(i, temp);
     deck.remove(temp);


    }

    return hand;
}

public void printHand(ArrayList<Card> hand)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
     Card temp = hand.get(0);
     System.out.println(temp.getRank() + " of " + temp.getSuit());

    }
}

public ArrayList<Card> getDeck()
{
    return this.deck;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks! In your opinion, would it make sense to instead have the deck loaded in the constructor of the Deck class, instead`of in a method? So that when I create a Deck object, it will automatically be an arrayList of of 52 Card objects. Is that possible or does it make any sense?

Comment: @Stephanie yes that would probably be the better approach.  You can leave the `loadDeck()` method in case you want to re-initialize a deck after it has already been created.  Just call the `loadDeck()` method in your constructor...

Comment: @Stephanie Maybe make the `ArrayList` part of the deck class to `private ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();` as a global variable...I'll post an example...